# Sinatra gives following error when installed on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack

I'm trying to install a simple hello world script using rack & sinatra.

So far I have got everything working perfectly on localhost, but when I try to upload to my server I get the following error when running via ssh:

```
rackup config.ru
```

It really just shows 'nothing'. I have to hit ^+C to abort. I tried

```
rackup config.ru --debug
```

I get this:

```
nil
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - no such file to load -- sinatra
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - no such file to load -- Win32API
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:62 - no such file to load -- Win32API
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - no such file to load -- mongrel
Exception `NoMethodError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rational.rb:78 - undefined method `gcd' for Rational(1, 2):Rational
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/gems.rb:7 - no such file to load -- mongrel_experimental
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247 - Could not find mongrel_experimental (>= 1.1.5) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.3, actionpack-3.1.3, activemodel-3.1.3, activerecord-3.1.3, activeresource-3.1.3, activesupport-3.1.3, arel-2.2.1, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.21, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.1.3, daemons-1.1.0, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-0.12.10, execjs-1.2.9, fastthread-1.0.7, gem_plugin-0.2.3, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, jquery-rails-1.0.19, json-1.6.3, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.17.2, mongrel-1.1.5, multi_json-1.0.4, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.3.5, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-protection-1.1.4, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.1.3, railties-3.1.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.11, rockhands-0.0.6, rubygems-update-1.8.12, sass-3.1.11, sass-rails-3.1.5, sinatra-1.3.1, sprockets-2.0.3, thin-1.3.1, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.31]
#<Rack::ContentLength:0x2b1ed5eebe88
 @app=
  #<Rack::Chunked:0x2b1ed5eebed8
   @app=
    #<Rack::CommonLogger:0x2b1ed5eec130
     @app=
      #<Rack::ShowExceptions:0x2b1ed490bd70
       @app=
        #<Rack::Lint:0x2b1ed490bdc0
         @app=Sinatra::Application,
         @content_length=nil>,
       @template=
        #<ERB:0x2b1ed490bd20
         @filename=nil,
         @safe_level=nil,
         @src=ALL MY HTML IS HERE
```

If this helps:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (3.1.3)
actionpack (3.1.3)
activemodel (3.1.3)
activerecord (3.1.3)
activeresource (3.1.3)
activesupport (3.1.3)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
daemons (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (1.2.9)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
json (1.6.3)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
mongrel (1.1.5)
multi_json (1.0.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.5)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-protection (1.1.4)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.3)
railties (3.1.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.11)
rockhands (0.0.6)
rubygems-update (1.8.12)
sass (3.1.11)
sass-rails (3.1.5)
sinatra (1.3.1)
sprockets (2.0.3)
thin (1.3.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
```

and

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: What's all the Win32 stuff about in the dump you posted? I guess that's not your problem? Also - if you are starting out on an app, perhaps start with ruby 1.9.2, since 1.8.7 will look old in a year or two, and the changeover is not always easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the app is not working?
For me `rackup` is also silent by default, but the app works fine on port 9292.

Just tested locally with the simplest ever Rack app:

```rb
# config.ru

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/plain' },
    "Hello World"
  ]
}
```

Oh and adding `--debug` also displays the same exceptions as yours, but the app runs fine.

I believe your application is actually working, but you can't access it for some reason. Perhaps port 9292 is not accessible remotely.

Try `telnet localhost 9292` on the remote machine to verify the app is working. You should see:

```
~$ telnet localhost 9292
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: it says Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
As a side quesiton, how do i access the app from the front end... just domain.com:9292? or does it know that its just domain.com/ i just tested it locally though and it refuses it too though. local works perfect

Comment: In the browser, `http://domain.com:9292` should work, assuming the port is open on the firewall. So how do you access the app running on localhost? If it works in the browser, telnet should also succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't mongrel_experimental a separate gem? Your stacktrace refers to it on lines 7 & 8, but it's not listed in you local gems. Try `gem install mongrel_experimental`.